# Is there a iOS standard for adding error messages to textFields?

Tags: swift, xcode, authentication, uitextfield, interface-builder

I am trying to perform text validation on my textFields for user login and sign up and I want to display error text depending on what the user inputs. I have been trying to find if there is any sort of default implementation for displaying error text in or around a textfield that I can build off of but I have not been able to find anything. Is there a solution that doesn't involve relying upon external libraries?

I already have the logic for validating the textFields but I just need to display messages to the user. This is what I have:

```
@IBAction func signUpButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        if (emailTextField.text == "") {
            print("Please enter an email.")
        } else if (passwordTextField.text == "") {
            print("Please enter a password.")
        } else if (confirmPasswordTextField.text == "") {
            print("Please confirm your password.")
        } else if (confirmPasswordTextField.text != passwordTextField.text) {
            print("Please ensure that your passwords are matching.")
        } else if (!emailTextField.isEmail()) {
            print("Please enter a valid email address.")
        } else if (!passwordTextField.isValidPassword()) {
            print("Passwords must be at least 8 characters in length and must contain at least one letter and one number.")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

your can use `UIAlertController` to show the error messages.

For textField use

```
yourTextfield.text = "Error Message"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a built-in solution that is really low-effort like

```
inputView.validationErrorMessage = "you must enter an email"
```

then no, there is no such thing built in to UIKit. However there are many built-in mechanisms that can be very easily used to show error messages.

For example, [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/windows_and_screens/getting_the_user_s_attention_with_alerts_and_action_sheets) can show a modal popup with possible options for them to choose from. Another approach is to add labels or imageviews that indicate a validation error and use the [isHidden](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622585-ishidden) property to show/hide them at the appropriate time.